# Undesired blank page between title and bibliography in apa6

Tags: biblatex, apa6

A blank page comes up between the title page and the bibliography each time I try to use biblatex-apa with apa6. The intent of the document is a listing of references with annotations.

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}

\shorttitle{Short Title}
\title{Regular Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University of Affiliation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography{annotate}
\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{mul2003,
   Author = {Muldoon, Orla T. and Reilly, Jacqueline},
   Journal = {Journal of Advanced Nursing},
   Number = {1},
   Pages = {93 - 100},
   Title = {Career choice in nursing students: gendered constructs as psychological barriers.},
   Volume = {43},
   DOI =   {http://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-2648.2003.02676.x},
   Year = {2003},
   Annote = {.},
}
```

Comment: The class's defintion of `\maketitle` includes two `\newpage`, so you have to redefine the command or patch it (e.g., with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`). I also don't think your `\refname` is guaranteed to work out of the box. And the other question is whether you want the reference list to start on page 2 or page 1.

Comment: The reference list would start on the second page of the document, i.e. the page after the title page. Would redefining the \newpage command break other functionality, like when the reference lists spills over to the following page?

Comment: Do not redefine `\newpage`! It will have far too many downstream effects. (But not the one you mention.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can 'patch' the `\maketitle` command from `apa6.cls`. (The command is far too long to want to copy the whole definition into your `.tex` file just to modify one or two lines.)

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mul2003,
   Author = {Muldoon, Orla T. and Reilly, Jacqueline},
   Journal = {Journal of Advanced Nursing},
   Number = {1},
   Pages = {93 - 100},
   Title = {Career choice in nursing students: gendered constructs as psychological barriers.},
   Volume = {43},
   DOI =   {http://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-2648.2003.02676.x},
   Year = {2003},
   Annote = {.},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

%\usepackage{etoolbox} This package is loaded by biblatex and csquotes
% otherwise you'd need to load it to use \patchcmd
% usage \patchcmd{<command to patch>}{<search string>}{<replace string>}{<success code>}{<failure code>}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\newpage}{}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Failure...}}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\newpage}{}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Failure...}}

\shorttitle{Short Title}
\title{Regular Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University of Affiliation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}
\printbibliography%{annotate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well!

Comment: @V.Fast -- Glad to hear it. If you feel this answer fully and properly answers the question you asked, consider marking it with the green check mark so that it comes off the unanswered list. (You are also welcome not to do so in the hope that you thereby encourage someone else to provide a better answer.)